# How to pump data into Rails Models from external sources (not web forms)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, automation

Are there any good practice on how can we insert data into a Rails App's models from an external source (not the web app), while still leveraging the ORM capabilities of active record? How possible is it for the ActiveRecord class be imported into our own external ruby script without the complete rails package? I was hoping to avoid writing raw SQLs as much as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

One way would be to use rake tasks within your app, which can access your ActiveRecord models. It will still load your app up, but not as a web service.

http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial

Also recommend this for more bulk style insert/updates:

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import